# Running Symfony 3.2 on the Server

Tags: php, symfony

I have Symfony 3.2 working dev application in my laptop, however, I needed to upload it on my server (cpanel).

The CPanel has PHP 5.5+ version running. I uses FTP to upload files from local computer to my server.

And when I try to access it in the browser `www.domain.com`, I only see the file directories, I mean, the page only shows the folders and files. But its not running the configuration, route, etc.

Any ideas? Please be inform that this is my first time to work in Symfony and upload it on the server.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Comment: 1) Make sure your webservers document root is set to /web in your symfony project folder
2) Are you running apache or nginx? Apache needs mod_rewrite enabled if you don't want to explicitly call app.php. For nginx you have to modify your site config.

Comment: @TobiasK. do you have link about that? so that I check.

Comment: I don't really know cPanel, but most hosting platforms like Plesk or cPanel will create a folder for your domain and suggest you to upload your files using FTP. The domain will then be routed to the root folder of your symfony project, which contains no index.php file. If no index file is found, the webserver will show a directory listing. You have to make sure that your domain routes to the web-subfolder in your symfony project and that only the web-folder is accessible from the outside.